# Web API - Suggestion for a method to retrieve the latest tracks added

Tags: spotify

I am currently using the Web API to track historical trends for the popularity of different artists / tracks. However, in order to maintain my records without accessing the Web API too often, a method that would return the latest tracks added to Spotify would be a great addition to the API. Do you think it would be possible to have something similar in the future?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This query shows the latest tracks added to Spotify, unfortunatelly it's only ordered by popularity, but perhaps it's a good solution for you:

http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album?q=tag:new

Comment: BTW, this solution only works for albums, but it's 100% accurate if you parse de XML correctly :)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't seem to find anything about the ":new" tag in the docs. Even though it's sorted my popularity, this method still helps me a lot as I don't have to search manually and crawl for all the tracks, check if I have them in my DB, etc...By the way, do you happen to know which tracks are tagged with "new" (latest n days or so).

Comment: From my experience these are the albums added on the last 7 days. You can parse all results by looping through pages using: http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album?q=tag:new&page=X and looping X from 1 to (totalResults / 100) + 1